# Any closed formula for $\mathcal{L}\big(u_c(t)\cdot f(t)\big) $?

Tags: laplace-transform

As in the title, is there any closed form formula for such Laplace transform, with denoting $\mathcal{L} \ f(t)=F(s)$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$\mathcal{L}\big(u_c(t)\cdot f(t)\big)=e^{-cs}\mathcal{L}f(t+c) $$

Comment: So, I want to compute $\mathcal{L}\big(u_\pi (t) \cdot (t e^t \cos t\big)$: Is it actually $e^{-\pi s}\mathcal{L} \big((t+\pi)e^{t+\pi})\cdot \cos (t+\pi) \big)$?

Comment: Yes, it is corect